# git/gitolite push issue - directory not allowed

Tags: git, gitolite

After correct (I hope) installation of gitolite, I cloned gitolite-admin repository to my local pc. Unfortunately, when I try to push changes to the server, I receive following error:

```
[me@PC gitolite-admin]$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 349 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Directory /var/lib/gitolite not allowed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/gitolite_rc.pm line 42.
remote: Compilation failed in require at hooks/update line 23.
remote: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at hooks/update line 23.
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
To my.server:/var/git/repos/gitolite-admin.git
![remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to my.server:/var/git/repos/gitolite-admin.git
```

Does anybody knows what is the cause of this issue?
Thank you in advance for a help.

Piotr

Comment: does the git user have read/write permissions on `/var/lib/gitolite`?

Comment: This is a gitolite v2 error. Please install gitolite V3. You can do a manual installation by cloning the gitolite GitHub repo and following  http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/install.html

Comment: Yeah, installation directly from the github solved the problem. Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 0):

As commented, installing a [Gitolite V3 or g3](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g3why.html) avoids what is a Gitolite g2 error in the update hook.

In Gitolite g3, it still reserves the `update` hook, but offers **[VREFS](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/vref.html)** which allows you to write all sort of other "update" hooks on your repos.